# Not a number output in c while trying to count average

Tags: c

I'm trying to tell the user to insert numbers as many as they can, and insert -1 if they want to terminate.  The program is working good, but I tried to enter -1 as a first number and I got this output : `-nan`

This is the code :

```
 main()
{
     int counter = 0;
     float grade;
     float total = 0;
     float average;
     printf("Compute the average grades.\n");
     printf("Grade = -1 will terminate the process\n");
     printf( "Enter grade (-1 to terminate): " );
     scanf("%f",&grade);
     while(grade != -1)
     {
         counter++;
         total+=grade;
         printf( "Enter grade (-1 to terminate): " );
         scanf("%f",&grade);
     }
     average = total / counter;
     printf("Class average is %.2f\n", average);

}
```

Comment: Consider what the value of `counter` is in the case you enter `-1` immediately. And then consider high school maths division.

Comment: Also, note that comparing float values for equality is not a good idea. See this paper for a detailed explanation: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Your program needs at least `#include <stdio.h>` and `main` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: The average of no numbers at all is not a number. That's exactly what your program prints.

Comment: Follow your program's control flow in your mind or on paper, and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
average = total / counter;
```

when `counter` is 0, which it is when you never iterate the loop body even once.

Wrap that line (and maybe the following output) into a

```
if(counter>0)
{
    //...
}
```

with a following

```
else
{
    //...
}
```

You can output something like
"No numbers, no average. ;-)".